# How to find a cycle containing a set of nodes in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Given a graph undirected G = (V,E) and a set of nodes P. I need to find a cycle (not the shortest length cycle) containing these nodes? How do I find this cycle?

Comment: do you have any conditions at all on the desired cycle?

Comment: There are no conditions on the cycle

Comment: Are you looking for Euler Cycles?

Comment: No I just need find a cycle which contains a given set of nodes of a graph

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222413/find-the-shortest-path-in-a-graph-which-visits-certain-nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contains Hamiltonian Cycle (for P = V), hence the decision problem (just knowing if there is such a thing) is NP-complete. So there is no efficient algorithm unless P = NP.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably start designing the algorithm by choosing the first node in P (let's call it P[0]), then running a depth-first search from P[0], taking note of anytime P[0] is again reached.  You would have to store the path taken to re-reach P[0] (or at least whether the other nodes of P have been reached) so that you know that any cycle you find contains all the nodes in P.  Running time should be the same as for depth-first search, which I believe is O(V + E).

Someone may come up with a better solution, and certain heuristics might be applied to help, but that should get you started.  (For instance, you may conclude you should start at the node of P with the fewest edges instead of starting at P[0].)

**Edit:**

One more thing I thought of...  When you reach another node in P via your depth-first search, there is no need for the DFS ever to "start over" from the very beginning or to consider paths that do not include this newly-found node.  This property could help your algorithm terminate more quickly in the case where no such cycle exists.

**Further edit:**

Never mind the last edit -- it would only work if it can be ascertained that there is no node in P on a different path between P[0] and the node in P reached that cannot be reached another way, and we wouldn't know that for sure without doing the whole DFS.

Regarding the answer about Hamiltonian cycles, I don't know how the cycle detection in the problem at hand is NP-complete.  Yes, we would have to traverse the entire graph (all vertices and edges) reachable from the start point to determine whether a cycle meeting the criteria of the problem at hand exists.  Further, we would need to know upon coming in contact with a previously-visited vertex what the "forward path" of the vertex would be to determine whether there is a cycle meeting the criteria.  Since we don't care about the shortest such cycle, though, I'm not sure how we are necessarily trying to find a Hamiltonian cycle.  Care to enlighten?

Comment: The Hamiltonian cycle goes through all nodes so there is not shorter or longer. Let me go step by step. Consider this special case of the question (and if the special case is NP-hard, the general case is NP-hard too): graph G = (V,E) and set of nodes P = V (that's what makes it a special case). Now the shortest and longest cycles through all nodes V is equally long, |V|. The problem becomes just finding if there is such a thing, and that's exactly Hamiltonian Cycle and it is NP-complete. So I just found HC "inside" this problem. The problem is not HC, but it contains it. Makes sense?