# Least Nodes Travelled Weighted Graph With Petrol Stops

Tags: graph-algorithm

What kind of algorithm would allow me to find the least amount of steps(traversing 1 edge is 1 day) to take to reach a certain vertex however if the car runs out of petrol than you would need to rest 1 day at that place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the shortest path in a graph which visits certain nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222413/find-the-shortest-path-in-a-graph-which-visits-certain-nodes)

Comment: that question has a restriction on nodes to visit =/

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. Does travelling to each vertex have the same weight as every other, or is it weighted?